# AngularFire Update rather than duplicate data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularfire

I'm using angularfire for to save and display my user data. The form they fill out stacks or duplicates the data rather than updating. I only want one to display the most recent data, any ideas?  I have it all contained in a panel and things like users name is listed 3 times.

```
app.controller('infoCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$firebaseArray', 'Auth', 
  function($scope, $location, $firebaseArray, Auth) {
  this.userAuthData = Auth.$getAuth();

vm = this;
var ref = new Firebase('https://capstone-zhf.firebaseio.com/' + this.userAuthData.uid + '/surveyInfo');
ref.orderByChild('name').limitToLast(2).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
});


vm.syncObject = $firebaseArray(ref);

var newInfo = {};

$scope.addInfo = function() {
    vm.syncObject.$add({
        q1: vm.newInfo.q1,
        q2: vm.newInfo.q2,
        q3: vm.newInfo.q3,
        q4: vm.newInfo.q4,
        q5: vm.newInfo.q5,
        q6: vm.newInfo.q6,
        q7: vm.newInfo.q7,
        weight: vm.newInfo.weight,
        height: vm.newInfo.height,
        name: vm.newInfo.name
    });
    vm.newInfo = {};
};
```

Here is my HTML code

```
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="(id, info) in infoCtrl.syncObject">
                  <td class="panel-body">Goal: {{ info.q1 }}</td>  
                  <td class="panel-body">{{ info.q2 }}</td>
                  <td class="panel-body">{{ info.q5 }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button ng-click="editNew(info)">Edit</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button ng-click="infoCtrl.syncObject.$remove(id)">x</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: You're calling `$add()`, which adds a new object to the array. If you want to update an existing object, call `$save()` See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-saverecordorindex

Comment: $Save still isn't adding the data to firebase and it still doesn't display yet.

Comment: Ok ill just comment it out... Your suppose to use Firebase.update() Function to update... https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html

Comment: That definitely works. I often fall back down to the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK when I don't know how to accomplish something in AngularFire. But @katowulf frowns at me when I do that. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going through it now. I appreciate the help.